# How do you comeup with multiple teams where work in interlaced and all deliver the same Single UI project

Tags: management, team, time-management, task-management

I currently hold a team of 17 all of whom work on delivering single product --Admin UI. The problem with such a big team is Grooming, Standups, dividing works, scaling new team members, handling resignations --I have to do all of them.

So i divided team into 5. And assigned a set of features to each team. Each team is given 1 new guy to rampup over a months time. (Except that, Requirements Grooming happens to all of them together). So major problems are solved. Even if people resign others in the team make sure we dont stop on delivery --meaning, now team is horizontally scalable

The problem comes when requirements come in. The founder says cash dries up in 1month. The client is at the door. Now, if i divide the work by responsibility some resources are hotspotted , some are too free (because client requirements majorly focus on enhancing certain features only) If I go and delegate work to the guy who is free in other team then eventually all 5 teams are becoming one monolith team (and its happening already). Now, the team is not taking ownership of their features (because the other guy from other team did some part of it)

So the question is: How do i handle this situation. Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Why split the team?

Comment: "The founder says cash dries up in 1 month" <- forget this job, it's deader than a dodo. Spend your time finding a new job.

Comment: @Kilisi When a person resigns i m finding it difficult to delegate  his tasts to another. So now i assign set of tasks to teams. I just make sure they have enough manpower. If somebody resigns/ new guy comes in they take of adjusting accordingly. Essentially I freed myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to run this as if it were a long term ongoing project, rather than something that has to be delivered in a month.

Forget trying to ramp up new people over a month if the project ends in a month. Work out what they can do now, even if it is something simple like proofreading documents.

Forget long term ownership of features.

Draw up a whiteboard with every remaining task on it. Prioritize the tasks. Assign the highest priority tasks to whichever person or team can do them.  Once a task is done, cross it off, and assign the next one. Keep repeating that. If every task that matters is done by the delivery date, you've won.

Answer (score 3):

If funding is going to dry up in a month and you're expecting resignations then you should also be job searching.

The risks are too high and directly impact your revenue stream. A month at a time has no stability.